# Jenkins is not able to connect to GIT with SSH, but shell works

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins

I have 2 Virtual Machines (both Ubuntu 12), SRV-ATLASSIAN (where Stash is installed) and SRV-CI (where Jenkins is installed).

I want to use the Git Plugin for Jenkins, so i installed it, created a SSH key on SRV-ATLASSIAN and copied the private key (id_rsa) to /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh

I ssh-add the key

When i type in

```
sudo su jenkins
cd /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh
git clone ssh://git@10.10.10.21:7999/test/test.git
```

on the shell, it does work perfectly.

When i enter this URI into the GIT Plugin of jenkins, i get the following error message:

```
Using strategy: Default
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from origin
ERROR: Problem fetching from origin / origin - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch -t origin     +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I've googled of course about this problem, but i don't understand what exactly to do to make it work. It is strange that i can clone from the shell AS THE USER "JENKINS" but Jenkins itself can't..

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the Jenkins user access to your Stash repos.  Create a user in Stash and add the SSH public key for the Jenkins user to the Stash user.  Then set up permissions for your Stash projects or individual repos so that the Jenkins user can access the repos you need.  See [the Stash docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Users+and+groups) for details.

Comment: I did it. I created a user called "jenkins". This user has permissions to the repository (READ). I created a user "jenkins" on the stash instance and create a new ssh key, copied the private key to the jenkins instance. Again, cloning on shell works, again get the same error.

Comment: You need to add the SSH public key for the Jenkins user on the Jenkins server to the Jenkins user in Stash.  As an adminstrator, go to https://stash/admin/users/view?name=jenkins and click the SSH Keys tab.

Comment: I removed all the keys, went to jenkins instance, created SSH key, added public key to jenkins user on stash. Restarted jenkins. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Maybe this helps finding the error, when i type in "sudo su jenkins" and i want to "ssh-add -l" then the output is: "The agent has no identities.". I have to "eval `ssh-agent -s` all the time to be able to clone from shell.